# How can I programmatically trigger "Done" function in UIImagePickerController (Camera)?

Tags: ios

I am currently using UIImagePickerController in my application to take advantage of the native iOS camera functionality.

However, I would like to either:

1) somehow programmatically trigger the method behind the "Done" button so my users don't have to

2) Skip the image preview of the camera without losing any of the existing UI functionality that the UIImagePickerController provides (like toggling flash, exposure, etc)

Use case: I am using a low energy bluetooth shutter button device to take a photo without pressing the capture button on the screen with my finger. I would like to also allow the user to press the bluetooth button to press the done button or just forego the done step completely and immediately return the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

Is this possible at all? Here is my implementation of my UIImagePickerController

```
@IBAction func presentCameraController() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            CameraAuthorization.GetAuthorizationStatus(completion: { granted in
                if granted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
                            let picker = UIImagePickerController();
                            picker.delegate = self
                            picker.sourceType = .camera

                        if let decider = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "cameraFlashEnabled") as? Bool {
                            if (decider) {
                                picker.cameraFlashMode = .on
                            } else {
                                picker.cameraFlashMode = .off
                            }
                        } else {
                            picker.cameraFlashMode = .on
                        }

                        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let encouragement = CameraAuthorization.EncourageAccess()
                    self.present(encouragement, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }

internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.selectedImage = image
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPhotoEditor", sender: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: Any reason this is being down voted? How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `showsCameraControls` to `false` and (if you want the user to have something to tap in order to take the picture) supply your own picture-taking interface. To take the picture, call (get this) `takePicture`.